# Error: failed to parse date field [2021-H1] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch dates from elastic search using unconventional date formats. My field in elastic search accepts these dates by having "ignore_malformed": true but when I try to fetch these dates I get this error. My date formats are: YYYY-Q[1-4] , YYYY-H[1-2], YYYY-[EARLY|MID|LATE]
Can anyone suggest how I can retrieve these dates/ranges?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here. Before we start, let's clarify the terminology. **Fetching** is probably just fine — your issue has to do with **ingesting** (and subsequently **parsing**) your custom date fields.

**Let's start with the most important point.**

#### There's no standardized date format for year quarters, halves, or "seasons".

As discussed in the thread [Is there a standard date format that expresses Quarters?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/119823/is-there-a-standard-date-format-that-expresses-quarters), different companies divide their years differently.

That said, Elasticsearch will only be able to parse the `year` component of your date strings. In order to enforce the three custom formats from your question, you could define the following mapping:

```json
PUT my-index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time_field": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "uuuu-['Q'][1][2][3][4]||uuuu-['H1']['H2']||uuuu-['EARLY']['MID']['LATE']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*BTW there's more on custom date formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).*

After that, you could attempt to ingest the three variants:

```json
POST my-index/_doc
{
  "id": "2021-Q2",
  "time_field": "2021-Q2"
}

POST my-index/_doc
{
  "id": "2021-H1",
  "time_field": "2021-H1"
}

POST my-index/_doc
{
  "id": "2021-LATE",
  "time_field": "2021-LATE"
}
```

In order to verify how the dates were parsed internally, you could utilize [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#script-fields) like so:

```json
GET my-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.id,hits.hits.fields
{
  "_source": "id", 
  "script_fields": {
    "exploring_time_field": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
             Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['time_field'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()),
             ZoneId.of('UTC')
          ).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which would return:

```json
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "2021-Q2"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "exploring_time_field" : [
            "2021-01-01 00:00:00"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "2021-H1"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "exploring_time_field" : [
            "2021-01-01 00:00:00"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "2021-LATE"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "exploring_time_field" : [
            "2021-01-01 00:00:00"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, since **only the year** component was extracted, the rest of the date time components were assigned the [default values for missing components](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#missing-date-components) (`Jan 1st 00:00:00`).

#### This is certainly not what you're after and so your best bet is to parse the custom date strings *before* you ingest them into Elasticsearch.